# How to put all form fields values in the same array with the same onChange function?

Tags: reactjs, forms, onchange

I have an add form for which I have a problem. I use the same `onChange` for each field but the state does not update when I enter a value. Except for the "gender" field...

Thanks!

Here's my add-on component:

```
const CreateModal = ({ open, handleCloseModal }) => {
  const {
    register,
    handleSubmit,
    formState: { errors },
  } = useForm();

  const [telephone, setTelephone] = useState("");
  const [isOpen, setOpen] = React.useState(open);
  const [personneData, setPersonneData] = React.useState({
    nom: "",
    prenom: "",
    genre: "",
    dateNaissance: ""
  });

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    const value = e.target.value;
    setPersonneData({ ...value, [e.target.name]: value });
  };

return (
    <div
      className="container m-auto"
      style={{ border: "1rem solid #DCDCDC", borderRadius: "3px" }}
    >
      <form name="addPersonne" method="post" onSubmit={handleSubmit(handleAdd)}>
        <FormControl fullWidth>
          <div className="d-flex justify-center mx-auto mt-4 mb-5">
            <h2>Ajouter une personne</h2>
          </div>
          <div className="form-group d-flex justify-content-between mx-3 mt-3">
            <TextField
              className={classes.root}
              defaultValue={personneData.nom}
              onChange={handleChange}
              name="nom"
              label="Nom"
              {...register("nom", {
                required: "Requis",
              })}
              error={!!errors.nom}
              helpertext={errors.nom && errors.nom.message}
            />
            <TextField
              className={classes.root}
              defaultValue={personneData.prenom}
              onChange={handleChange}
              name="prenom"
              label="Prénom"
              {...register("prenom", {
                required: "Requis",
              })}
              error={!!errors.prenom}
              helpertext={errors.prenom && errors.prenom.message}
            />

            <FormControl component="fieldset" className={classes.root}>
              <FormLabel component="legend">Genre</FormLabel>
              <RadioGroup
                className={classes.root}
                row
                name="genre"
                {...register("genre", {
                  required: "Requis",
                })}
                error={!!errors.genre}
                helpertext={errors.genre && errors.genre.message}
              >
                <FormControlLabel
                  className={classes.root}
                  onChange={handleChange}
                  value='1'
                  checked={personneData.genre === '1'}
                  control={<Radio />}
                  label="Femme"
                />
                <FormControlLabel
                  onChange={handleChange}
                  value='0'
                  checked={personneData.genre === '0'}
                  control={<Radio />}
                  label="Homme"
                />
              </RadioGroup>
            </FormControl>
          </div>

          <div className="form-group d-flex justify-content-between my-5 mx-3">
            <TextField
              className={classes.root}
              defaultValue={personneData.dateNaissance}
              onChange={handleChange}
              name="date_naissance"
              label="Date de naissance"
              type="date"
              InputLabelProps={{
                shrink: true,
              }}
              {...register("dateNaissance", {
                required: "Requis",
              })}
              error={!!errors.dateNaissance}
              helpertext={errors.dateNaissance && errors.dateNaissance.message}
              style={{ width: "40%" }}
            />
          </div>

          <div className="d-flex justify-content-between my-4 mx-3">
            <Button
              className="btn btn-secondary"
              role="button"
              onClick={handleClose}
            >
              Annuler
            </Button>
            <Button className="btn btn-primary" role="button" type="submit">
              Ajouter
            </Button>
          </div>
       </FormControl>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};

export default CreateModal;
```

I would like to build on the `onChange` an array that would look like this: `[field name: 'field value']`. I tried several things but nothing works. Could you help me (I'm new to react.js).

Answer (score 0):

I'm actually not sure why any of your fields work. I would actually expect gender *not* to work, since the controls that have the onChange event do not have the name genre. Try changing handleChange like this:

```
  const handleChange = (e) => {
    const value = e.target.value;
    setPersonneData({ ...personneData, [e.target.name]: value });
  };
```

Also, consider using useReducer for this.

Comment: thank's for your answer I've already try this solution but it's still not working. You talk about useReducer, i'm not sure to know how to use it. Could you show me please?

Comment: What happens if you `console.log(e.target.name, e.target.value)` in handleChange?
Also, https://blog.logrocket.com/react-usereducer-hook-ultimate-guide/